# Partial hyphenated wildcard sub domain dns records

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard

**What are the correct DNS records for `{any}-the-sub.example.com`?**
While avoiding  CNAME `*.example.com`

For extended subdomain `{any}.the-sub.example.com` that would be something like:

```
the-sub.example.com     A       0.0.0.0
*.the-sub.example.com   CNAME   the-sub.example.com
```

However same doesn't apply when using hyphen `{any}-the-sub.example.com`.
nor the `*-the-sub.example.com` or `*the-sub.example.com` wont work right?

Comment: nothing in the DNS spec.

Comment: @Andrew I beleave you are correct this is duplicate since [accepted answer](http://serverfault.com/a/504937/163684) there does kind of answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Wildcards in DNS only apply to whole labels (labels are the parts of domain names between dots). Nothing in general DNS does what you ask for.

It is possible that some particular DNS server software may have a functionality to auto-generate records according to the sort of rules you describe, but I'm not personally familiar with any.